# Initial conditions making trouble with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, complex

I want to solve a number of differential equations in a single `NDSolve`. The code is as follows:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + 3 x'[t] Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] + 
Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]]) == 0, 
a'[t]/a[t] == Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4], \[Tau]'[t] == 1/a[t], 
Q''[t] + 3 Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] Q'[t] + (7.41169*10^6)^2/(a[t])^2 Q[t] + 
(3 (x'[t])^2 - (x'[t])^4/(2 ((x'[t])^2/6 + (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4)) + 2 x'[t]*Sqrt[3/2] Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]] (1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])/Sqrt[(x'[t])^2/6 + 
(1 - Exp[-x[t] Sqrt[2/3]])^2/4] - Exp[-2 Sqrt[2/3]*x[t]]*(Exp[Sqrt[2/3]*x[t]] - 2)) Q[t] == 0, 
x'[0] == -0.008226306418212731, x[0] == 5.630991866033891, 
a[0] == 1, \[Tau][149.4517772937791] == 0, 
Q[0] == 0.00032266726624148926 - 0.00314603057601689*I, 
Q'[0] == 317.79077568451766 + 32.595243081882664*I}, {x, \[Tau], a, Q}, {t, 0, 500}];
```

The code runs fine without `Q[t]` initial conditions and differential equation, so my guess it that the initial conditions are giving some trouble when the computation is being done, because when running the former code, Mathematica gives:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/Sqrt[0.] encountered.
General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
```

So, is it because the initial conditions for `Q[t]` are complex-evaluated? Hope to find an answer.

Edit: For some physical context, the differential equation for `Q[t]` is the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation, which I am trying to solve for a potential `V=3/4(1-Exp[-Sqrt[2/3]\[Phi][t]])^2`, but in the code I just use `\[Phi][t]=x[t]`. The initial conditions come from the Bunch-Davies vacuum, which means that $lim_{k/aH\rightarrow\infty}u_k(\tau)=\frac{e^{-ik\tau}}{\sqrt{2k}}$, where $u=aQ$, $\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\frac{1}{a}$, and $\tau$ is the conformal time in terms of $t$.

Comment: Solution without `Q` shows huge values  `(...10^32)` 
 for `a[t]`. Is this intended?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, yes, since it increases exponentially fast.

Comment: But values of order `10^32` might indicate some numerical instability